# Use Regex To Match Word At Start Of Line Or Preceded By Space

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the word "hello" only if it starts at the beginning of a line OR is preceded by a space.

So far I have tried:

```
^|(?<=[ ])hello
```

But that only matches words that come after a space. Anyone know why the `^` is not being interpreted?

Comment: You could use `(?<!\S)hello\b` or `(?<=^| )hello\b`

Comment: That's a pretty good alternative, thanks. Still curious what I am doing wrong though.

Comment: The start of the string `^` should be in the lookbehind or else `^|(?<=[ ])hello` means assert the start of the string or match hello when on the left is a space. But what you want is to assert what is on the left is either the start of the string or a space.